# Firestore Database Rules Get document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Being honest, i'm a bit lost with what i'm trying to do in firestore.

For this simple situation, I want to get a value from a different collection, that has nothing to do with user.

However, I keep getting a malformed error.  Any help?

My issues are around the **//NOT SURE IF {business} IS CORRECT HERE** and **//I WANT TO GET THE THE RECORD WHERE THE AREAS.NAME == DASHBOARD.**

(it will contain the allowed users for that specific area that i will match against the users role later on)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    //match /{document=**} {
    //  allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
    //}

    //NOT SURE IF {business} IS CORRECT HERE
    match /business/{business} {
        //I WANT TO GET THE THE RECORD WHERE THE AREAS.NAME == DASHBOARD
        allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/areas/{}).data.name == "dashboard";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "table" ? Did you mean collection?

Comment: Sorry just a typo mistake. Sql days

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a specific document id to access document from another collection

```
    match /business/{business} {
        allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/areas/document_id).data.name == "dashboard";
    }
```

Comment: I get a simulation write failed. Also tried passing it as a function and passing in the hardcoded value of the id like:  allow write: if getArea("IDHere") == "dashboard";  but nope doesn't work.  it definitely exists.